# Display ImageButton on last slide of viewpager

Tags: android-studio, android-viewpager

I'm trying to have a button appear only on the last page of a `ViewPager`. I have the working button but it is displayed on all the pages instead of only the last page. I want to have it visible only on the last page. Here is my code.

activity_welcome2.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:context=".Welcome_Activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!--- for dots -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:alpha=".5"
        android:layout_above="@+id/dotsLayout"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dotsLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55sp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/next3"
            android:layout_width="99dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.822"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/next" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Welcome_Activity.java

```java
package com.group7.salitongue;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

public class Welcome_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager mPager;
    private int[] layouts = { R.layout.activity_main, R.layout.activity_splashscreen2, R.layout.activity_welcome };
    private MpagerAdapter mpagerAdapter;

    private LinearLayout Dots_Layout;
    private ImageView[] dots;

    private ImageButton nextBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome2);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        mpagerAdapter = new MpagerAdapter(layouts, this);
        mPager.setAdapter(mpagerAdapter);

        Dots_Layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dotsLayout);
        createDots(0);

        mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                createDots(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
        });

        // transition button to Signup page
        nextBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next3);
        nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Welcome_Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void createDots(int current_position) {
        if(Dots_Layout != null)
            Dots_Layout.removeAllViews();

        dots = new ImageView[layouts.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < layouts.length; i++) {
            dots[i] = new ImageView(this);
            if (i == current_position) {
                dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.active_dots));
            }
            else {
                dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.default_dots));
            }

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
            params.setMargins(4, 0, 4, 0);
            Dots_Layout.addView(dots[i],params);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I display the button only when the user has reached the last page of swiping?

Answer (score 0):

Just listen in the `onPageSelected` method of your `OnPageChangeListener` when the last page is reached and set the button to visible. In all other cases, just hide it.

```java
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    createDots(position);
    // only show the button when the last page is reached
    if (position == mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1)
        nextBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        nextBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```